# How can I get a &str returned here?

Tags: rust

When I try to run this:

```rust
use std::thread::LocalKey;

struct Person {
    name: String,
}

impl Person {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Person {
            name: name,
        }
    }
    
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        self.name.as_str()
    }
}

thread_local! {
    static NAMED_THING: Person = Person::new("John".to_string());
}

fn retrieve_name(p: &'static LocalKey<Person>) -> &str {
    p.with(|n| n.name())
}

fn main() {
    println!("The name is {}", retrieve_name(&NAMED_THING));
}
```

it tells me

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:24:18
   |
24 |     p.with(|n| n.name())
   |                  ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 24:12...
  --> src/main.rs:24:12
   |
24 |     p.with(|n| n.name())
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:24:16
   |
24 |     p.with(|n| n.name())
   |                ^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
```

I could do instead:

```rust
fn retrieve_name(p: &'static LocalKey<Person>) -> &str {
    p.with(|n| n.name().to_owned().as_str())
}
```

But it seems pretty wasteful to clone that string every time. Not to mention, it now tells me:

```rust
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:24:16
   |
24 |     p.with(|n| n.name().to_owned().as_str())
   |                -------------------^^^^^^^^^
   |                |
   |                returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                temporary value created here
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=00a9cb53901b8cf829fc69d69229788d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.

The `Person` will be destructed when the thread ends, and then any reference to it (for instance, a `'static` reference which has been sent to another thread in the mean time) would become dangling. That's why `LocalKey` has a `with` method, instead of implementing `Deref` like `lazy_static` variables do: because taking a `'static` reference to a thread-local value is unsound.

You need to organize your code so all the borrowing is confined to the scope of the closure passed to `with`. For example:

```
fn print_name(p: &'static LocalKey<Person>) {
    p.with(|n| println!("The name is {}", n.name()));
}

fn main() {
    print_name(&NAMED_THING);
}
```